# How to make multiple transaction with same account in quickbook through XML

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have an account of payments Received in QuickBook which has the money received from customers. I have multiple consecutive entries which are deducting payments from the same for multiple payments. So the payment which is done is depended upon the last entry and the balance updated after it. How should i generate the XML for the same?

For example it's cash in drawer. Now there is fee coming for a service along with the expence which have to be deducted via different entries. Like if i have 15000 cash in drawer and for a transaction i'm receiving 1000 fees and at the same time i want to credit the expense of 400 from cash in drawer. So i'm sending journal entries for crediting 1000 and for debit. As i have last balance of Cash in drawer stored in my db i prepare the xml assuming 15000 cash which gets updated after first. So 2nd entry becomes invalid. And i dont know how to get updated balance.

Comment: Your question is very, very confusing. Perhaps you could post some screenshots illustrating what you're trying to do? Or post what you've tried so far with qbXML?

Comment: For example it's cash in drawer. Now there is fee coming for a service along with the expence which have to be deducted via different entries. Like if i have 15000 cash in drawer and for a transaction i'm receiving 1000 fees and at the same time i want to credit the expense of 400 from cash in drawer. So i'm sending journal entries for crediting 1000 and for debit. As i have last balance of Cash in drawer stored in my db i prepare the xml assuming 15000 cash which gets updated after first. So 2nd entry becomes invalid. And i dont know how to get updated balance.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. thank you for your response. 
I found it. As there is few documentation available on quickbooks i've been wondering how to know the previous balance. For any transaction what you have to give is account id and two journal entries. `Creditline` and `Debitline` . I was thinking that i have to know the balance for these operations. and Quickbooks processes the XML one by one so there won't be any Racing condition.